# All curves do not appear in ggplot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, graph

I have the following data, trying to generate my graph using ggplot in `R`. I have three questions:

1. Why I do not have all the curves in my graph? only a few of them appear.
2. How to add only the cluster legend to my graph?
3. How to not have different line types? (a solid line type is fine for all the curves).

Thank you

**My Code:**

```
transposed_data <-t(Rank_Cum_Xp_Sorted[,-c(ncol(Rank_Cum_Xp_Sorted)-1,ncol(Rank_Cum_Xp_Sorted))])
rownames(transposed_data) <- seq(1, nrow(transposed_data))
final_table <- melt(transposed_data, id.vars=rownames(transposed_data))
clusters <- data.frame(
  name = rownames(Rank_Cum_Xp_Sorted),
  Cluster = Rank_Cum_Xp_Sorted$Cluster
)
final_table <- final_table %>%
  left_join(clusters, by = c("Var2" = "name"))

final_table$Cluster[final_table$Cluster==1]<-"A"
final_table$Cluster[final_table$Cluster==2]<-"B"
final_table$Cluster[final_table$Cluster==3]<-"C"
final_table$Cluster[final_table$Cluster==4]<-"D"
    
    bp <- ggplot() +
    geom_line(data=final_table, aes(x = Var1, y = value, color = Cluster,group=Var2),lwd=1) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c('limegreen','blue','black','red')) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("Ranks")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(1,length(Dates),1)), labels = Dates)+
    theme(text = element_text(size=15,face="bold",color="Black"), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,color="Black"), 
          axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0,color="Black"))
bp <- bp + theme(text = element_text(size=15,face="bold",color="Black"), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,color="Black"), axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0,color="Black"))
bp <- bp + annotate(geom="text", x=73, y=30, label=round(mean(Rank_Cum_Xp_Sorted[RowIndex_Cluster_One,ncol(Rank_Cum_Xp_Sorted)]),2),color="red",angle = 90,size=5) +
scale_color_manual(values=c('limegreen','blue','black','red'), labels = c("Regular", "Disheartened", "Achievers", "Underachievers"))
```

**My Data:**

```
Rank_Cum_Xp_Sorted <- structure(list(V3 = c(52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 30.5, 52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 30.5, 52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 
32, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 30.5, 52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 67.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 67.6666666666667, 30.5, 52.6666666666667, 
52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 67.6666666666667, 
52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 89.5, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
32, 30.5, 39.1666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 52.6666666666667, 31.5, 52.6666666666667, 
52.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667), V4 = c(57.25, 
37.5, 57.25, 37.5, 23.875, 57.25, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 23.875, 
57.25, 57.25, 26.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 57.25, 32.25, 
37.5, 37.5, 57.25, 23.875, 57.25, 41.5, 37.5, 57.25, 37.5, 37.5, 
57.25, 37.5, 57.25, 37.5, 37.5, 52.75, 57.25, 37.5, 57.25, 57.25, 
68.5, 23.875, 57.25, 57.25, 57.25, 57.25, 37.5, 57.25, 37.5, 
37.5, 37.5, 57.25, 57.25, 37.5, 37.5, 57.25, 57.25, 57.25, 68.5, 
57.25, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 57.25, 57.25, 89.625, 37.5, 37.5, 24.25, 
23.875, 37.5, 57.25, 57.25, 37.5, 57.25, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 57.25, 
37.5, 37.5, 57.25, 57.25, 57.25, 25.625, 57.25, 42.375, 37.5, 
37.5), V5 = c(60.4, 38.1, 60.4, 38.1, 20.8, 60.4, 38.1, 38.1, 
38.1, 38.1, 20.8, 60.4, 60.4, 21.4, 38.1, 30.5, 38.1, 33.7, 38.1, 
60.4, 30.3, 38.1, 38.1, 60.4, 20.8, 50.3, 36.1, 38.1, 46.6, 38.1, 
38.1, 60.4, 33.7, 60.4, 38.1, 38.1, 45.1, 50.3, 38.1, 60.4, 60.4, 
69.4, 20.8, 60.4, 60.4, 60.4, 60.4, 38.1, 60.4, 31.7, 38.1, 38.1, 
60.4, 60.4, 38.1, 38.1, 60.4, 60.4, 60.4, 69.4, 60.4, 33.7, 38.1, 
38.1, 60.4, 60.4, 89.7, 31.7, 38.1, 19.9, 20.8, 38.1, 60.4, 60.4, 
38.1, 60.4, 33.7, 38.1, 38.1, 60.4, 38.1, 38.1, 60.4, 60.4, 48.7, 
23.4, 60.4, 38.4, 38.1, 31.7), V6 = c(62.75, 39.1666666666667, 
62.75, 39.1666666666667, 19.0833333333333, 62.75, 39.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 19.0833333333333, 
62.75, 62.75, 18, 39.1666666666667, 25.8333333333333, 39.1666666666667, 
31.8333333333333, 35.5, 51.1666666666667, 29.8333333333333, 39.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 62.75, 19.0833333333333, 46.5, 30.9166666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 39.6666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 
62.75, 31.8333333333333, 62.75, 35.5, 39.1666666666667, 40.4166666666667, 
46.5, 39.1666666666667, 62.75, 53.1666666666667, 70.25, 19.0833333333333, 
62.75, 62.75, 62.75, 62.75, 39.1666666666667, 62.75, 28.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 62.75, 62.75, 39.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 62.75, 62.75, 62.75, 70.25, 62.75, 31.8333333333333, 
39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 62.75, 62.75, 89.75, 28.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 17, 19.0833333333333, 39.1666666666667, 62.75, 
53.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 62.75, 31.8333333333333, 
39.1666666666667, 39.1666666666667, 62.75, 39.1666666666667, 
39.1666666666667, 62.75, 62.75, 43.4166666666667, 22.3333333333333, 
62.75, 36.5833333333333, 39.1666666666667, 28.1666666666667), 
    V7 = c(63.8571428571429, 37.0714285714286, 65.9285714285714, 
    43.6428571428571, 19.8571428571429, 58.5714285714286, 43.6428571428571, 
    43.6428571428571, 43.6428571428571, 39.6428571428571, 18.2857142857143, 
    62.3571428571429, 65.9285714285714, 15.5714285714286, 43.6428571428571, 
    22.4285714285714, 43.6428571428571, 28.0714285714286, 36.5, 
    44.6428571428571, 32.1428571428571, 43.6428571428571, 37.0714285714286, 
    65.9285714285714, 19.8571428571429, 47.7142857142857, 28.9285714285714, 
    43.6428571428571, 34.7857142857143, 43.6428571428571, 35.0714285714286, 
    65.9285714285714, 32.7142857142857, 58.3571428571429, 35.8571428571429, 
    43.6428571428571, 38.1428571428571, 45.2857142857143, 37.0714285714286, 
    63.8571428571429, 47.7857142857143, 67.3571428571429, 19.8571428571429, 
    60.9285714285714, 65.9285714285714, 58.5714285714286, 63.8571428571429, 
    43.6428571428571, 62.0714285714286, 27.6428571428571, 43.6428571428571, 
    35.0714285714286, 65.9285714285714, 61.6428571428571, 43.6428571428571, 
    35.0714285714286, 60.9285714285714, 62.0714285714286, 60.9285714285714, 
    68.5, 56, 32.7142857142857, 40.7142857142857, 43.6428571428571, 
    60.9285714285714, 65.9285714285714, 89.7857142857143, 24.9285714285714, 
    37.0714285714286, 16.5, 19.8571428571429, 43.6428571428571, 
    65.9285714285714, 46.3571428571429, 37.0714285714286, 59.2142857142857, 
    32.7142857142857, 41.4285714285714, 39, 57.2857142857143, 
    43.6428571428571, 37.0714285714286, 60.1428571428571, 60.9285714285714, 
    38, 22.6428571428571, 65.9285714285714, 37.7142857142857, 
    43.6428571428571, 25.6428571428571), V8 = c(65, 36.9375, 
    68.375, 45.625, 21.875, 56.6875, 42.6875, 47.3125, 47.3125, 
    35.5625, 18.625, 62.5625, 61.125, 13.8125, 47.3125, 20.1875, 
    47.3125, 25.9375, 38.3125, 39.25, 34.75, 47.3125, 36.9375, 
    68.375, 21.875, 49.1875, 28.75, 47.3125, 31.8125, 47.3125, 
    32.75, 68.375, 30, 51.625, 32.75, 47.3125, 37.875, 40.1875, 
    36.9375, 65, 44.9375, 65.875, 21.875, 59.25, 68.375, 56.6875, 
    65, 45.625, 57.4375, 26.8125, 47.3125, 32.75, 68.375, 56.5625, 
    47.3125, 32.75, 60.25, 62.125, 60.25, 67.75, 52.125, 34.5625, 
    42.5625, 47.3125, 59.25, 68.375, 89.8125, 23.1875, 36.9375, 
    17.0625, 21.875, 47.3125, 68.375, 41.9375, 36.9375, 57.75, 
    29.1875, 43.6875, 40.0625, 54.625, 47.3125, 36.9375, 56.25, 
    59.25, 34.625, 22.4375, 68.375, 39.5, 47.3125, 24.5), V9 = c(61.0555555555556, 
    38.0555555555556, 70.2777777777778, 47.2777777777778, 24.6666666666667, 
    56.6666666666667, 43.1666666666667, 50.4444444444444, 45.3333333333333, 
    32.5555555555556, 17.5, 62.0555555555556, 58.5, 12.4444444444444, 
    50.4444444444444, 18.5, 50.4444444444444, 23.6111111111111, 
    40.7777777777778, 35.0555555555556, 37.7777777777778, 47.2777777777778, 
    38.0555555555556, 70.2777777777778, 24.6666666666667, 51.1111111111111, 
    29.7222222222222, 50.4444444444444, 29.9444444444444, 50.4444444444444, 
    31.7222222222222, 70.2777777777778, 28.3333333333333, 46.4444444444444, 
    30.7777777777778, 45.3333333333333, 38.8888888888889, 36.2777777777778, 
    38.0555555555556, 66.1666666666667, 43.8333333333333, 65.6666666666667, 
    24.6666666666667, 54.3333333333333, 70.2777777777778, 56.6666666666667, 
    66.1666666666667, 43.8333333333333, 54.9444444444444, 27.1111111111111, 
    50.4444444444444, 31.7222222222222, 70.2777777777778, 53.5555555555556, 
    50.4444444444444, 31.7222222222222, 60.6666666666667, 62.8333333333333, 
    60.6666666666667, 67.8333333333333, 50.2222222222222, 32.3888888888889, 
    40.4444444444444, 47.2777777777778, 54.3333333333333, 70.2777777777778, 
    89.8333333333333, 22.2777777777778, 38.0555555555556, 18.4444444444444, 
    24.6666666666667, 50.4444444444444, 70.2777777777778, 38.9444444444444, 
    38.0555555555556, 53, 26.5, 46.2222222222222, 42.1666666666667, 
    53.7777777777778, 50.4444444444444, 38.0555555555556, 54.3333333333333, 
    58.7777777777778, 32.4444444444444, 23.2222222222222, 70.2777777777778, 
    37.4444444444444, 50.4444444444444, 23.4444444444444), V10 = c(57.75, 
    41.3, 71.25, 42.95, 28.75, 58.05, 46.7, 49.6, 44.7, 31.5, 
    16.95, 58.3, 54.3, 11.3, 47.05, 16.85, 46.05, 21.55, 44.3, 
    32.05, 37.2, 47.2, 40.15, 66.05, 28.75, 48.8, 30.15, 51.7, 
    32.55, 54.3, 36.75, 69.25, 27.7, 45.55, 34.55, 42.3, 35.95, 
    34.65, 40.05, 62.75, 47.65, 64.3, 27.4, 53.8, 71.65, 58.6, 
    68.35, 44.1, 55.55, 32, 54, 33.75, 68.25, 56.05, 50.05, 31.35, 
    61.15, 62.75, 58.8, 65.25, 50.8, 34.75, 44.6, 47.95, 56.2, 
    71.95, 89.85, 21.4, 37.8, 21.25, 24.65, 46.05, 66.05, 35.85, 
    38.45, 54.55, 27.4, 48.15, 45.25, 52.15, 46.35, 36.45, 50.7, 
    54, 31.1, 25.1, 71.75, 36.9, 46.75, 28.4), Cluster = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("AF", 
"AT", "BP", "CJ", "DC", 
"Fa", "FD", "Gonreira", "Gones", 
"Joãoeja", "Joãoeira", "Lueda", "reitas", 
"Luísnho", "Migeiro", "Natalideiro", "Nunoia", 
"Nunode", "Pedrro", "Ricar]ra", "Ricilva", 
"Rúbeines", "Tomaczewski", "Vasdro", "Adal", 
"Andra", "Antcheco", "Catarrêa", "Dioçalves", 
"Filres", "Fredeira", "Gonadeiro", "Jomador", 
"Joãorreto", "Joardal", "Jiro", "Josas", 
"Lonçalves", "Manurnandes", "Manurigues", "Marcilva", 
"Marreira", "Miguz", "Migcisco", "Migldes", 
"Migopes", "Paurreira", "Pedreiro", "Peoura", 
"Runcho", "Svonen", "Tontos", "Andguel", 
"Danodrigues", "Dominkova", "Francirata", "Guilhemes", 
"Joãsta", "Joues", "Jontos", "Jostos", 
"Márntos", "Migurino", "Rtos", "Stins", 
"Toues", "Yau", "Antino", "Ancisco", 
"Aniidian", "Anvares", "Birlar", "Caartins", 
"Diogimo", "Francilado", "Inêreira", "Irigues", 
"Joãado", "Joãres", "Joãlo", "Joãego", "Jooso", 
"Lulva", "Magnde", "Miguas", "Migegas", 
"Paloçalves", "Pbral", "Pemes", "Raquóvão"
))
```

Comment: You have different line types because you’re setting it to Var2 in geom_line().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer point by point.

1. Some of your lines disappear because you have more different `Var2` values that ggplot can come up with linetypes, so the excess of `Var2` values are given no line. Like Elle suggested in the comments, you can show all clusters if you remove `linetype = Var2` from your aesthetics. Instead, you can use the `group` aesthetic to specify a line-separating variable.
2. Assuming you've removed the aforementioned linetype, just remove `theme(legend.position = "none"). Because you now don't have linetypes, only the cluster legend shows.
3. See answer 1.

Code example:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=final_table, aes(x = Var1, y = value, color = Cluster,group=Var2),lwd=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('limegreen','blue','black','red')) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Ranks")+
  theme(text = element_text(size=15,face="bold",color="Black"), 
                 axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,color="Black"), 
                 axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0,color="Black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You @teunbrand. Just one minor question, How can I change the labels in legend to the other ones? I want to have black color as Achievers, green as Regular, blue as Disheartened and red as underachievers. I have tried 'scale_color_manual' but i get an error.

Comment: You can use the `labels` argument in that function, e.g. `scale_color_manual(values=c('limegreen','blue','black','red'), labels = c("Regular", "Disheartened", "Achievers", "Underachievers"))`.

Comment: Actually I have used it but I get this warning : "Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the existing scale." FYI, I edited your code a bit to match my needs

Comment: Yeah you should only use one colour scale per plot (unless your using the ggnewscale package). But does it give the labels as you wished?

Comment: Yes, it gives. Should I upload the code as an answer here that you check it out?

Comment: Probably best to append any extra code to your question itself. But doesn't simply deleting the previous `scale_colour_*` function solve the warning problem then?

Comment: It seems that removing the `scale_colour_manual()` in the line below the `geom_line()` removes the warning.